# How to save a file in Julia

Tags: julia

At some point, (I think Julia v0.7) you could do `@save savepath thingtosave` in order to save files using Julia. I tried to run this on v0.7 to see if I got a deprecation warning but even on 0.7 it says that `@save` is undefined.

How can I programmatically save files using Julia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mention `@save`, presumably, you were using [JLD.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) or its successor [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl).

A simple example for using JLD2 would be

```
julia> using JLD2

julia> @save "test.jld2" x

julia> x = nothing # "forgetting" x

julia> @load "test.jld2"
1-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :x

julia> x
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.698264  0.319665
 0.252174  0.80799
```

In contrast to `write`, those packages are based on [HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) (through [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl)). They pretty much allow you to store arbitrary Julia objects. HDF5 (not necessarily JLD/JLD2) is a file format which is supported by almost all programming languages and many programs (Mathematica for example). It is suitable for long-term storage in contrast to `read`/`write` which might change in future Julia versions.

Note that this doesn't show up in 0.7 since it is a package feature and not part of Base (or a stdlib).

Comment: Does this inherently do the same thing as `read` and `write` do? Or should I start using `JLD2`?

Comment: It is very much different from `write`. It is based on HDF5. Think of JLD/JLD2/HDF5 as a more higher-order binary format (`write` is more low-level I'd say). Another point is that HDF5 is a long-term data storage format whereas, AFAIK, the binary serialization underlying `write` might change in future Julia version.

Comment: One thing to mention though is that JLD.jl is/was in a state where almost no one cared about maintaining it (and JLD2.jl is not a feature-equivalent drop-in replacement). So, if you really care about long-term guarantees it might be better to go with the underlying HDF5.jl.

Comment: Another important point is that almost all languages have a way to read HDF5 files whereas the binary output of `write` (if you don't go down the rabbit hole) is basically only for you to read back in. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

[From the julia docs, there is the `write` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.write):

```
write(io::IO, x)
write(filename::AbstractString, x)

Write the canonical binary representation of a value to the given I/O stream or file. Return the number of bytes written into the stream. See also print to write a text representation (with an encoding that may depend upon io).

You can write multiple values with the same write call. i.e. the following are equivalent:

  write(io, x, y...)
  write(io, x) + write(io, y...)
```

writing a text file:

```
write("text.txt","this is a test")
```