# How to load a file in Julia?

Tags: julia

At some point, (I think Julia v0.7) you could do `@load loadpath thingtoload` in order to load files using Julia. I tried to run this on v0.7 to see if I got a deprecation warning but even on 0.7 it says that `@load` is undefined.

How can I programmatically load files using Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is too vague. How to load a file very much depends on the kind of file you have. Do you want to read in a binary file? What kind of binary file? Or maybe a text file?

However, since you mention `@load`, presumably, you were using [JLD.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) or its successor [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl).

A simple example for using JLD2 would be

```
julia> using JLD2

julia> @save "test.jld2" x

julia> x = nothing # "forgetting" x

julia> @load "test.jld2"
1-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :x

julia> x
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.698264  0.319665
 0.252174  0.80799
```

Note that this doesn't show up in 0.7 since it is a package feature and not part of Base (or a stdlib).

(See also the cousin thread [How to save a file in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58382775/2365675))